# predicate to identify an object exists in a set

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have a many-to-many relationship. I have test handled in multiple servers and servers contain multiple tests. Both has name as an attribute. I have to get all `testTypes` which has selected server as a subset of server (relationship attribute). server attribute will be a set. I tried using `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"servers contains %@",server]]` or `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"servers.name contains %@",[server name]]]`.

So in my tableView once I select a specific server it should display all testTypes which has tat server as a subset. I could not find anything suitable for doing so in net.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY servers = %@", server]]` ?

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I did a mistake. I passes server instead of self.server and thus i was nil.

Comment: OK, I am glad to hear that. I have added it as a proper answer, so you can "accept" it if you like (by clicking on the check mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all `testTypes` objects that are related to `self.server`, use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY servers = %@", self.server]]
```

Comment: Along with that 

    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"server contains[cd] %@",server]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"server.name CONTAINS[cd] %@",[server name]]];

can also be used to find all testType objects that are related to server.